# In Vb.Net, how to remove duplicate items but leave at least one of the duplicate items in the list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, list, items

I have a List object and I want to remove the duplicated items but leaving at least one of the duplicated items in the list;

I wrote something like this however I would optimize this code for better performance, is there something faster?

```
Const chars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim mylist As List(Of String) = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(Function(i) chars(rnd.Next(0, chars.Length)).ToString).ToList

For n As Integer = mylist.Count - 1 To n = 0 Step -1

    'remove the item if it's duplicated
    'but leave at least one of the duplicated items in the list
    If mylist.IndexOf(mylist.Item(n), 0) < n Then
        mylist.RemoveAt(n)
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Can you use `.Distinct()` from LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried   `.Distinct()`

```
Dim stringWithChars As String = "AABBCCDDEEFFaabbccddeeff"
Dim res = stringWithChars.Distinct() // ABCDEFabcdef
```

Edit: Since you didn't say which framework you use, I suppose you **can** use Linq ( .NET 3.5 +)

Comment: Thank You, I can use Distinct() to List objects too

Comment: but have I to sort the list before call distinct()?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `Distinct` works on a string as Alex suggested, but another solution is to convert the string to a char array before calling `Distinct`. Here's an example:

```
var test = "abcdefggabc";

test = new string(test.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
```

**EDIT**: Alex tested this on a string and it works, so either solution would work.

If you're looking for an alternative to LINQ, you should be able to achieve this with a regex too. Something like this might work:

```
var test = Regex.Replace("JJJJJ DDDD KK  YYYYY", @"(.)(\1)+", "$1");
```

Comment: I tested it on a string though ;) - dont let the "chars" variable fool you in my snippet. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Alex's answer works because String implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)`. It is worth knowing this - people [have been known](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/02/01/use-iterators-in-vb-now.aspx) to write their own custom iterators to go through the chars in a string!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of a List?